# How to properly set a timezone in a clojure REPL?

Tags: clojure, timezone, read-eval-print-loop, leiningen

When running a query on a postgres database on a clojure REPL, the timestamps fields are presented in UTC and I need them to be in timezone America/Sao_Paulo (UTC-3)

So far I have tried the following on Intellij's REPL:

- Set `-Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo` inside the file `idea.vmoptions` (intellij's)
- Add `:jvm-opts ["-Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo"]` to project.clj
- Add `-Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo` in Intellij's REPL configuration
- export `JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo:$JAVA_OPTS"` inside `~/.zshrc`

and the following on Leiningen REPL:

- Add `:jvm-opts ["-Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo"]` to project.clj
- export `JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo:$JAVA_OPTS"` inside `~/.zshrc`

None worked so far!

Sample code

```
(ns experiments
  (:require [next.jdbc :as jdbc]))

(def db
  {:dbtype   "postgres"
   :dbname   "<dbname>"
   :host     "<host>"
   :port     5432
   :user     "<user>"
   :password "<pass>"})

(def ds (jdbc/get-datasource db))

(jdbc/execute! ds ["select current_timestamp"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention any Postgres options.  Please study [this page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/datatype-datetime.html#:%7E:text=PostgreSQL%20assumes%20your%20local%20time,being%20displayed%20to%20the%20client.) carefully for info and options.

If the above does not solve your problem, it may be easiest to use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) to do the conversion.   I also have some helper/convenience functions [available here](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.214/api/tupelo.java-time).  [Unit tests](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/clj/tst/tupelo/java_time.clj) show them in action, and [the source code](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/src/clj/tupelo/java_time.clj) provides examples of `java.time` interop from clojure.

I would avoid the older Joda Time libraries as they are obsolete (replaced by java.time). I think that Java interop is the easiest & most straightforward way to access `java.time`.